# Create a custom product form based on user role in magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, products, adminform

I want to hide some field of the product creation form.

I know that i can do this with some **xml** file, but i want to hide them only for specific user role.

I found that the event `adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_prepare_form` is **triggered** when the product form is created, but it doesn't fire.

The events `catalog_product_edit_action` and `catalog_product_new_action` instead work, but they are triggered when the new or edit buttons are clicked.

How can i modify the form?